# Dynamic Object Attribute "protected"

Tags: c#, json

I'm having trouble with a certain bit of data in the Twitter API. One of the values returned is '"protected":bool'. When converting the JSON to a dynamic object, I cannot access the protected value, because 'protected' is a keyword. I've also tried a method I've seen using reflection:

```
data.GetType().GetProperty("protected").GetValue(data, null)
```

But get the exception "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference." data is not null as immediately before this line other attributes are parsed out, and protected is not null as I can see through the raw response that the value exists in the Json.

Is there any way to get a property named 'protected' from a dynamic object?

Comment: To use keywords as property names just put a @ before them `data.@protected`

Comment: @juharr I think your comment actually is the answer

Comment: @juharr Worked like a charm, thanks so much.